Bluetooth speaker detected as Handsfree (Sounds like a phone call) 24.04
When connecting the speaker, it detects as Handsfree, it has 'Headphone' option in sounds settings, but when I click it, it disappears. The problem only appeared after I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04.


I solved the problem by re-installing ubuntu-restricted-extras from multiverse.
